# Unable to Import data using BCP utility and w switch

Tags: bcp

I have a tab delimited file which has unicode characters and has LF as line ending. When I try to import this file using bcp utility and -c switch it loads into the table, however, the characters are not correct. And when I try to use the -w switch it fails to load with below error.

"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file"

Below is text in the file

```
ialgcd  ianvmn  sourceVersion
PT  Português   2021-06-W24
SP  español 2021-06-W24
EG  English 2021-06-W24
FR  Français    2021-06-W24
GE  Deutsch 2021-06-W24
RU  Русский 2021-06-W24
PB  Português(Brazil)   2021-06-W24
KR  한국어 2021-06-W24
CH  中文  2021-06-W24
```

If I use -c switch in the below manner it loads without error. But incorrect characters

```
bcp TableName1 in DelimitedFile1.txt -c -T -S Server01 -q -t \t -r 0x0A -F2
```

If I use -w switch it does not load any data and throws error

```
bcp TableName1 in DelimitedFile1.txt -w -T -S Server01 -q -t \t -r 0x0A -F2
```

I tried all different types of combinations for the line terminator and field terminators and also tried using -N switch and also tried using a format file but nothing works.

The format file I tried to use is

```
14.0
3
1       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\t"         1     ialgcd                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\t"         2     ianvmn                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "0x0A"       3     sourceVersion                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

I am not sure why does it work with -c switch and not with -w switch. Is it expecting a BOM character at the start of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this issue. -w switch will work for Unicode characters but if your file is UTF-8 encoded then you have to use the -C (upper case C) and the code page number so for UT-8 it will be 65001 along with the -c switch (lower case c)

So the command will look like

```
bcp TableName1 in DelimitedFile1.txt -c -C 65001 -T -S Server01 -q -t \t -r 0x0A -F2
```